# How to interface hypercorn and starlette web framwork

Tags: python-3.x, starlette, hypercorn

I was able to get it up and running with gunicorn and uvloop, but having a hard time getting this working with hypercorn. Another issue is specifying the number of workers for ASGI frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a line like `app = Starlette(debug=True)` the `app` is an ASGI application that can be run by Hypercorn (or other ASGI servers). If this line is in a file called `run.py` you can run it via `hypercorn run:app`.

If you want multiple workers (2 shown) you can do `hypercorn -w 2 run:app`. If you want uvloop as well, `hypercorn -w 2 -k uvloop run:app`.